# How to update BabeAuthorityWeight and NextAuthorities from custom pallet?

Tags: babe, pos

I would like to customize the POS. I did read some article about how to implement that, and used `pallet_babe`, my custom pallet and also `pallet_staking`.

I found that in order to update the authorities for the next block, it is configured in `enact_epoch_change()` with `AuthoritiesId` and `BabeAuthorityWeight` in babe.

However, the target is updating the `nextAuthorites`, and `BabeAuthorityWeight`, I
I tried with `SessionManager` to update the `validator set` for my custom pallet, then assigned the custom pallet `SessionManager` in `pallet_session`. But I am not sure how this set would become the `nextauthorites` in `pallet-babe`?

Please give me a lead.